# Filtering (Query) docs based on HashMap from Firestore -android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to filter and get docs which wrote to Firestore. So my collections inside I have one more HashMap

> doc1

```
//.....

"votes": [
{
  "userID1": true,
  "userID2": true,
}],

//.....
```

> doc2

```
//.....

"votes": [
{
  "userID1": true,
  "userID2": true,
}],

//......
```

[Please check here my Firestore snapshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blf8f.png)

Now I need to filter all userID1 (Highleteed in attached image)where is equal to true.

I tried code as below seems not working

```
// Construct query basic query
mQuery = mFirestore.collection(fsCollection)
        .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .whereEqualTo(getUid(), true)
        .limit(LIMIT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
mQuery = mFirestore.collection(fsCollection)
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo(getUid(), true)
            .limit(LIMIT);
```

with

```
mQuery = mFirestore.collection(fsCollection)
            .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .whereEqualTo("votes." + getUid(), true) //Use the name of the HashMap
            .limit(LIMIT);
```

Because you are using `orderBy` and `whereEqualTo` methods in the same query, you'll need to create an index. In the moment you start your app, you'll see in the logcat a `url`. Click on that url to create the needed index.

Comment: Thank you so much Alex Sir if it works I don't need to duplicate data to per users, But the votes can be written as below string .whereEqualTo("votes/" + getUid(), true), just want to confirm before trying out. Thank you.......

Comment: Yes, it works thank you so much again Alex, but after creating an index, it shows me current Uid in the index (votes.GBJN9gPzNzO timestamp enabled), then for every user, it alerts me in Logcat to creating an index, so needs to be indexed?

Comment: ok done and only one more..  what if I did not create the indexes however it is showing data

Comment: No, it did not. Cloud Firestore requires an index for every query, to ensure the best performance. If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. **The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.**